# How to export from PostGIS to KML

Tags: postgis, kml

What is the best way to export from PostGIS to KML using open source tools?

Can I do it directly, or do I need to first export to shape files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to perform the operation:

```
 ogr2ogr -f "KML" mykml.kml PG:"host=myhost user=myloginname \ 
             dbname=mydbname password=mypassword" "myschema.mytable" \
             -s_srs EPSG:<myEPSGcode> -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

Comment: One shortcoming of `ogr2ogr` in this instance is that you can't generate attribute-dependent styles or a load of other stuff (like `<TimeStamp>` and `<TimeSpan>` tags for 'tour' creation). Far better to bite the bullet and hand-craft **(1)** the query to get attributes and geometry in almost-XML (an `xml_agg()` of a bunch of nested `xmlelement()`s and an `ST_AsKML(geom)::xml`); then **(2)** wrap (1) in the XML tags required to document namespaces, styles, schema etc. You only ever have to get it right once: then **template that shizzle**, brah.

Comment: ogr2ogr was not designed in the first place to accomplish what you referring as a shortcoming. Templating a kml and then filling in the values later on as you describe, yes its an interesting functional approach. Another way would be if you'd be really familiar with the kml schema, to directly draw the locations from a database, and go lower with programming library (ie pyKML) to develop more general solutions.

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in the comment to the first answer, `ogr2ogr` will get you a **very** simplified KML (with a `name` and `description` field if you specify them with `-dsco`, but little else).

So long as you're careful about structures, you ought to be able to write a query that will output what you need, including conditional styles and so forth.

For example, here's an example query that will extract single-style data and save it to a KML (including adding a JSON-like data object to the `description` tag so that aspatial - 'attribute' - data can be amended by end-users). It's the simplest example - it has no conditional styles and only one variable.

It's a bit of a schemozzle... but it works. Square brackets `[]` indicate  variables - i.e., should be replaced by your own variables, schemas, table names etc.

```
    COPY (
SELECT xmlelement(
    NAME kml,
    XMLATTRIBUTES ('http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' AS xmlns),
    xmlelement(
        NAME "Document", XMLATTRIBUTES ('[yrDocID]' AS id),
        xmlelement(NAME NAME, '[yrKMLName].kml'),
        xmlelement(NAME OPEN, 1),
        xmlelement(
            NAME "Folder",
            xmlelement(NAME NAME, '[yrFolderName]'),
            xmlelement(
                NAME "Schema",
                XMLATTRIBUTES (
                '[yrSchemaName]' AS NAME,
                '[yrSchemaID]' AS id
                ),
                xmlelement(
                    NAME "SimpleField",
                    XMLATTRIBUTES (
                    '[yrFieldType]' AS TYPE,
                    '[yrFieldName]' AS NAME
                    )
                )
            ),
            xmlelement(
                NAME "Style",
                XMLATTRIBUTES ('[yrStyle_01]' AS id),
                xmlelement(
                    NAME "LineStyle",
                    xmlelement(NAME "color", 'ff0000ff'), /* alpha first, then B G R (i.e., RGBA, backwards) */
                    xmlelement(NAME "width", 4)
                ),
                xmlelement(
                    NAME "PolyStyle",
                    xmlelement(NAME "fill", 0)
                )
            ),
            xmlagg(
                xmlelement(
                    NAME "Placemark",
                    xmlelement(NAME NAME, [yrFieldName]),
                    xmlelement(
                        NAME "TimeSpan",
                        xmlelement(NAME "begin", 2009),
                        xmlelement(NAME "end", 2017)
                    ),
                    xmlelement(
                        NAME "description",
                        '{editMe: , editMeToo: , Notes: }'
                    ),
                    xmlelement(NAME "styleUrl", '#[yrStyle_01]'),
                    xmlelement(
                        NAME "ExtendedData",
                        xmlelement(
                            NAME "SchemaData",
                            XMLATTRIBUTES ('#[yrSchemaID]' AS "schemaUrl"),
                            xmlelement(
                                NAME "SimpleData",
                                XMLATTRIBUTES ('[yrFieldName]' AS NAME )
                                , [yrFieldName]
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    ST_AsKML(ST_Transform(g1, 4326)) :: XML
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
    FROM [schema].[table]
    WHERE [conditions]
)
TO '[outfile].kml'
```

The best reason to do it this way, is that you can incorporate any part of the KML spec - which you can't do with `ogr2ogr`.

For example, you could *conditionally style* each polygon based on its attributes, or add `<TimeSpan>` behaviour (for Tours: in the example above they're actually implemented in the wrong place in the hierarchy).

It's a bit of a pfaff, though: you either need to generate a set of Document or Folder-level `<Style>` tags (and possibly `<StyleMap>` if you have style hierarchies) and apply them conditionally to individual `<Placemark>` using `<StyleUrl>`.

Alternatively, put each different 'class' into its own `<Folder>`: to do this requires

- an extra `xml_agg()` enclosing the `xmlelement(NAME "Folder",[snip]`;
- `GROUP BY` some set of things that generates your thematic classes at the end of the query; and
- the `name` for each new class-based `Folder` should be created as part of the query.

Then you can have `Folder`-level styles, one per `Folder`.

I'm not really a fan of using PostgreSQL to do this (the code example is legacy code). It makes more sense to drag the data (with geometry `ST_AsKML()::xml`) into Python or PHP and generate the XML iteratively.

If you examine the code at [this Google Developer page about using PHP and mySQL to generate KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml#outputkml), you can see the bits that need to be changed to get the data from PostgreSQL instead. That plus the [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference) should get you over the line.

Comment: Is there a way to also include the version tag header: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the really begining of the KML?

Answer (score 2):

postgis has this [functionality](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsKML.html) out of the box, if you linked it to proj -- check this using [PostGIS_Full_Version](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Full_Version.html) -- that addressed, an example of the functionality follows:

```
SELECT ST_AsKML(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0))',4326)) as kml

kml
--------
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```