# Convert PostGIS geometry + 3 orientation parameters to a KML Camera object using SQL only

Tags: postgis, postgresql, kml, 3d-orientation

I have some WKB PostGIS Point geometries in WGS84.

I also have some orientation parameters for these geometries, stored as angles in degrees, namely, heading, tilt and roll values.

I want to build a KML for them expressed as a [Camera](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/cameras) object.

Does it exist a native PostGIS function for that? Or do I have to build my own? I've found that [ST_AsKml](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsKML.html) can do that but for the position only (it seems there is no possibility to also include the orientation):

```sql
SELECT ST_AsKML(location) FROM my_point_table LIMIT 1;
```

which returns:

```xml
"<Point><coordinates>-122.4790,37.8110,127.0</coordinates></Point>"
```

But I do have angular values as well in separate Postgres columns:

```
heading: 18.0    
   tilt: 85    
   roll: 0
```

I wish I could directly output a KML like this using, as shown on the KML webpage linked hereabove, by only Postgres/PostGIS function(s):

```xml
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Golden Gate tour</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Camera>
      <longitude>-122.4790</longitude>
      <latitude>37.8110</latitude>
      <altitude>127</altitude>
      <heading>18.0</heading>
      <tilt>85</tilt>
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
    </Camera>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

I'm surprised, I *must* have missed such obvious thing in PostGIS, right?
Or else, I didn't search in the right direction... Hence my question.

**Information**

These are the only 'ST_AsKML' function's signatures I can see in my schema:

[image: st_askml functions in postgis 3.1]

From the [Docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated): `postgis/postgis:13-3.1`

PostgreSQL: PostgreSQL 13.1 (Debian 13.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit

PostGIS: 3.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

By the way, I noticed there are less signatures than in PostGIS 2.4:

[image: st_askml functions in postgis 2.4]

Comment: I think the only way is to use pykml https://pythonhosted.org/pykml/examples.html built by Google https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2012/01/introducing-pykml-python-library-for.html as a post-postgis manipluation.

Comment: There is COPY method from Postgres https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64850/how-to-export-from-postgis-to-kml

Comment: Thank you. I've indeed implement a Python script using pykml and it works, except that the KML isn't valid according to the OGC KML Schema because it lacks the `gx:TimeStamp` element, but that's not a big deal. I will check if I can build a trigger using this `COPY` statement, which sounds great. But I'm now wondering if it's worth storing this along the original values in the database as it doesn't really bring up new information... I know that some developers are not happy with that idea of duplicating things because it can downgrade the performances or what ever.